# Cannot connect to ftp server via browser but I'm able connect from terminal using ftp server_addr

Tags: networking, server, vsftpd

I installed vsftpd and in the beginning I was able to connect via browser as well as from terminal using ftp server_addr.
Now I'm unable to connect via browser but able to connect from terminal
Please help me connect via browser also

Comment: Have you checked if there are any options in /etc/vsftpd.conf file that may be interfering with browser connection?

Comment: Try to use ftp://server_addr. On this way you will specify protocol to browser. Ftp work on `port 21`, http on `port 80`. Check firewall.

Comment: Can you please post your `vsftpd.conf` to http://paste.ubuntu.com so we can have a look at the details?  It works fine on my machine...

Comment: here it is (http://paste.ubuntu.com/10659207/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy one. Add

```
anon_root=/srv/ftp
```

or whatever directory you wish. That one is just the default as per the [file Hierachy standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/)

The `anon_root` will be the "root directory" that anonymous users (from a web browser) will connect to…

To see all of the parameters:

```
man vsftpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is too late.
But i had the same trouble right now.
I spnd about two hours to solve this.
I just try to share result with the next...

Edit your **vsftpd.conf** and add/edit (change the "/home/" directory):

```
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=50000
# Root dir for logged users
local_root=/home/
# For an anonymous access
#anon_root=/home/
```

And allow those ports in ufw:

```
ufw allow 40000:50000/tcp
```

Have a good luck!